# Function returns generic class of base interface - Type mismatch

Tags: generics, kotlin

The second to last line doesn't compile but the last line compiles fine:

- What is the reason (they seem equivalent to me)?
- What can I change so that `return if(true) m1 else m2` will compile?

Compile error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is `Hold<HelloMsg>` but `Hold<Msg>` was expected

```
interface Msg
class HelloMsg: Msg
class ByeMsg: Msg
class Hold<T: Msg>(val msg: T)

fun test(): Hold<Msg> {
  val m1 = Hold(HelloMsg())
  val m2 = Hold(ByeMsg())
  return if(true) m1 else m2                             //DOESN'T COMPILE
  return if(true) Hold(HelloMsg()) else Hold(ByeMsg())   //COMPILES
}
```

Comment: I think I have the answer to my second question: `fun test(): Hold<out Msg> { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What can I change so that return if(true) m1 else m2 will compile?

Make `Hold` [covariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance): `class Hold<out T: Msg>(val msg: T)`. Then `Hold<HelloMsg>` and `Hold<ByeMsg>` will both be subtypes of `Hold<Msg>`.

> I think I have the answer to my second question: `fun test(): Hold<out Msg> { ... }`

Yes, that works too, but more locally. `class Hold<out T>` is basically equivalent to making *all* uses of `Hold` marked with `out`.

> What is the reason (they seem equivalent to me)?

In the `if(true) m1 else m2` case the types of `m1` and `m2` are already fixed by their declaration and different from `Hold<Msg>`.

In the `if(true) Hold(HelloMsg()) else Hold(ByeMsg())` the compiler is typing `Hold(HelloMsg())` while knowing it has to be `Hold<Msg>`. So it infers the type parameter as `Hold<Msg>(HelloMsg())`. Same with the other branch.